# Limpiar Input File desde controller .Net

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc, .net-core

Estoy trabajando sobre .net core en donde en mi vista tengo un input file y hago post con un Boton el cual me envia directamente el archivo haciendo post a mi controller el cual procesa el archivo y me retorna otro de regreso.
necesito poder limpiar el input file cada vez que se envie un archivo obligado a que el usuario suba nuevamente un archivo y no que el mismo que subio antes se le quede pegado. Agradezco cualquier colaboracion ya que estoy iniciando en programación.

mi HTML lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "UploadFile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <label for="file" class="col-1" align="right">File:</label>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="form-control-file col-11" onchange="return fileValidation()">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <button disabled="disabled" id="btnUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="disableButton()">Upload File</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Cómo tienes tu código del controlador? Estas haciendo un return View(model) en tu método que recibe el post?

Comment: ¿Ya viste el workshop que te recomendé o iniciaste algún curso del tema? revisa https://Microsoft.com/Learn